# Account summary shows different reputation points than on the actual account

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, linked-accounts, reputation-summary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

On my Stack Overflow account, reputation points for Game Development and Android Enthusiasts shows **1 rep** but when I navigate physically to these accounts I see my reputation points as **▾ladiesMan217 101**. What's the cause?

Here's the proof of the account summary https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004239/ladiesman217?tab=accounts

Here's are the actual account pages that display 101 reputation points
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14558/ladiesman217
https://android.stackexchange.com/users/13135/ladiesman217

Comment: It must be a glitch in the "ladiesMan" filter.  Your computer was actually supposed to explode in flames.  Consider yourself lucky.

Comment: lol what? explode in flames? I still don't understand whats the cause

Comment: There's caching and then there's caching. It's not helped by the recent changes to rep that mean other changes (deleted/migrated) now show up immediately. I've got an account that's showing 35 more rep than it should do following a migration over the weekend.

Comment: Seems to have finally synched up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long has it been out of sync? If you only just created accounts on those pages it may take a while for the stats to update for other Stack Exchange Websites.

**EDIT :**
as darvidsOn has noticed, it's been longer then what you'd expect for a simple syncing problem. If the problem isn't resolved in a few days (from this question being up) i'd suggest emailing the Stack Exchange team. their contact page can be found [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact). Note that they suggest posting to meta, so I'd only use this as a last resort.

Comment: Yep, it's sync delays. The sync between your SE account and individual site accounts isn't immediate, a rule of thumb is if it hasn't updated within 24 hours then something may be broken.

Comment: Though now I note the OP joined Android Enthusiasts on March 5th.. definitely something up there.

Comment: You don't need to e-mail the team, that's what this site is for.

Comment: @CodyGray That's why i said to use it as a last resort, if meta doesn't have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there's clearly something odd going on.

I had an answer moved with 35 rep from Webmasters to Stack Overflow on [17 March at 15:01](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/27153/timeline).

My Rep on Webmasters fell back to 953, and my rep on SO increased appropriately, and is currently at 14,390.

The accounts summary and pages all list the correct rep for all my accounts (including Meta which only hit 871 10 minutes ago or so) except for Webmasters which still shows the incorrect 988 rep:

[image: Incorrect Rep]

Looks like there's an issue with the calculated rep adjustments not triggering a cache update or something?

Comment: Yea and if I go to Android Enthusiasts it shows some of my recent account's reputation as 1